# UITableView reuse cells nightmare, how to stop repeating after 4 row without reusing cells for performance matter?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to figure the right way of doing the following: displaying 3 buttons in each row of the UITableView. But it keeps repeating, and when I removed the if(cell == nil) it stops repeating but when I scroll back to the top the old rows get blank. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    pageNumbers = [models count]/3;
    pageNumbers+=1;
    return pageNumbers;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if(totalRows+1 <= [models count])
        {
            UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 104, 160);
            IconEntity* iconForImage = [models objectAtIndex:totalRows];
            [btn setImage:iconForImage.TheImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btn setTag:1];

            UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];

            NSString* some_name = iconForImage.TheName;
            lbl.text = some_name;
            lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 80, 80);

            [btn addSubview:lbl];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];

            totalRows+=1;
        }

        if(totalRows+1 <= [models count])
        {
            UIButton* btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn2.frame = CGRectMake(108, 1, 104, 160);
            IconEntity* iconForImage = [models objectAtIndex:totalRows];
            [btn2 setImage:iconForImage.TheImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btn2 setTag:2];


            UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            lbl.text = iconForImage.TheName;
            lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 80, 80);

            [btn2 addSubview:lbl];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:btn2];
            totalRows+=1;
        }

        if(totalRows+1 <= [models count])
        {
            UIButton* btn3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn3.frame = CGRectMake(216, 1, 104, 160);
            IconEntity* iconForImage = [models objectAtIndex:totalRows];
            [btn3 setImage:iconForImage.TheImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btn3 setTag:3];


            UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            lbl.text = iconForImage.TheName;
            lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 80, 80);

            [btn3 addSubview:lbl];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:btn3];
            totalRows+=1;
        }


    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, 440)];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```

It doesn't repeat anymore, but I can't scroll back that the cells get blank

Comment: try to be helpful and comment after downvoting and voting to close

Comment: This question is very vague. If you want to create a cell with 3 buttons, make a nib for the cell and load that. It's even easier in a storyboard, as you can just add prototype cells. Also, what is this `totalRows` variable? Are you sure you don't want `indexPath.row` or something like that?

Comment: totalRows exist to count the next images from Mutable array, indexPath doens't help since I am grouping 3 elements for one cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if(totalRows+1 <= [models count])
        {
            UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 104, 160);
            IconEntity* iconForImage = [models objectAtIndex:totalRows];
            [btn setImage:iconForImage.TheImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btn setTag:1];

            UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];

            NSString* some_name = iconForImage.TheName;
            lbl.text = some_name;
            lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 80, 80);

            [btn addSubview:lbl];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];

            totalRows+=1;
        }

        if(totalRows+1 <= [models count])
        {
            UIButton* btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn2.frame = CGRectMake(108, 1, 104, 160);
            IconEntity* iconForImage = [models objectAtIndex:totalRows];
            [btn2 setImage:iconForImage.TheImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btn2 setTag:2];


            UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            lbl.text = iconForImage.TheName;
            lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 80, 80);

            [btn2 addSubview:lbl];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:btn2];
            totalRows+=1;
        }

        if(totalRows+1 <= [models count])
        {
            UIButton* btn3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn3.frame = CGRectMake(216, 1, 104, 160);
            IconEntity* iconForImage = [models objectAtIndex:totalRows];
            [btn3 setImage:iconForImage.TheImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btn3 setTag:3];


            UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            lbl.text = iconForImage.TheName;
            lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 80, 80);

            [btn3 addSubview:lbl];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:btn3];
            totalRows+=1;
        }


    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, 440)];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It works. But I was wondering how I can reuse the cells when scrolling for performance matters.